Azure DevOps - deploy Window Service task
I have a pipeline set up with multiple deployment groups. On one of my deployment groups, the service gets installed on the C: drive. On the other, to a different location on the E: drive.
On a new deployment group I set up, the target destination is the source destination as is failing because the file already exists, or if I do a 'clean' install, I obviously get the 'file not found' error.
I examined the tasks and neither specify a target location. I also checked the environments, and there is nothing that points to a target location.
Here is the associated YAML:
steps:
- task: MDSolutions.WindowsServiceManagerWindowsServiceManager.WindowsServiceManager.WindowsServiceManager@4
  displayName: 'Deploy Windows Service'
  inputs:
    DeploymentType: DeploymentGroup
    ServiceName: My.Portal.Service
    ArtifactPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Portal.UI/My.Portal.UI/winservice'
    TimeOut: 600

I verified the tasks are the same between the two deployment groups.
What am I missing?
Thank you

You need to use class release editor for the task with deployment group. if you use yaml for pipeline, it's running on the agent machine not deployment group machine.
As mentioned in the doc:

You can follow below steps with the task:

I have build pipeline to create the artifact of the service.exe as below, you can refer to the link about the build steps.



Consume the build artifact in the release pipeline. Add deployment group job to use the machine.


The WindowsServiceManager task will check if the service exists on the machine or not.


Since my service file in zip, tried on my side, the task seems copied nothing to the installation path, which will cause service fail to start.
To install the service and start it, you can extra the zip file to a folder, and specify installation path to the file, so that the service can start.

The result:

If the service already existed on the deployment machine before the pipeline, the task will automatically find the service file path, will not use installation path.

You can use clean install to clean the old files, and copy from extracted path as artifact path to get the service file.



the service gets installed on the C: drive. On the other, to a different location on the E: drive.

Hence, you can check if the service already exists on the agent before, as it could use original path.

I see what you are saying is the 'correct' way, but all of the deployments are configured the same and I don't see why each deploys to different locations.  I'll keep reviewing to see what I am missing.  I am using classic release pipelines.  (There was a button to show YAML so I choose that to attach to the question.)

@JoeDerham, the task will check if the service exists on the deployment group machine, and if it does, it will automatically detect the service installation path, and copy the service file to that path. It could cause different drive C and E on your pipeline. Of course, if both are newly deployed service, you can confirm the installation path under install service. Please check the answer above for the details.

For the deployment failure, you can follow the two deployment settings(service existing and not-existing) for your task to have a check.

I am beginning to suspect the services were manually installed, and then the deployment task just picked it up from there.  I am trying your way so it can install fresh.

Yes please. You can also open service list on deployment group machine to confirm if same service exists. If it does, you can right click on service and stop it, then launch command with admin permission, type sc delete servicename to remove it. Then you can follow the newly deployment settings to deploy again to double check the drive C or E.

@WadwZhou - Thanks for your input!  I got it working by following your example.

Glad to know it's working! Happy coding!
